# Concat URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, concatenation, file-get-contents

I have a problem when I try concatenate variables with a URL

This works:

```
$id = 123;
$url = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/table.json?output=html&udptype=trap&udpmsgid=".$id."&content=udpmessage");
```

But this doesn't work

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$url = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/table.json?output=html&udptype=trap&udpmsgid=".$id."&content=udpmessage");
```

I don't know if I'm concatenating the variables properly.

Comment: `$_GET['id']` is not defined.

Comment: I think id is empty or as this.lau_ told!

Comment: use isset and check  $_GET['id'];

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this,

```
if(!empty($_GET['id']))
{
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $url = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/table.json?output=html&udptype=trap&udpmsgid=".$id."&content=udpmessage");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, use **[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $url = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/table.json?output=html&udptype=trap&udpmsgid=".$id."&content=udpmessage");
}
```

Comment: Would that give him what he wants though? Instead he should probably call this script in such a way that $_GET['id'] is defined.